# Display an item in a list by referring to the number of times present in another list.

Tags: python

I am trying to display each item in string_list. But the number of times to display each item is in display_times list. The code should display a 2 times, b 3 times and c once. This is what I have got which is not correct. What should I do next?

```
string_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
display_times = ['2', '3', '1']

for item in string_list:
    for times in display_times:
        print("It is " + item)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution

```
In [12]: for s, t in zip(string_list, display_times):
    for i in range(int(t)):
        print "It is %s" % s
   ....:         
It is a
It is a
It is b
It is b
It is b
It is c
```

Comment: you can change it to `for i in range(int(t))`. You don't need that zero

Comment: You don't need the loop at all. `print s*int(t)`

Comment: Not sure if that's what he wants.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a good understandable way to do it:

```
zipped = zip(string_list, display_times) #equal to [('a', '2'), ('b', '3'), ('c', '1')]
for value, time in zipped:
    for i in range(int(time)):
        print value
```

result:

```
a
a
b
b
b
c
```

Answer (score 2):

The first problem you have that is the `display_times` list is storing *strings* and not numbers.

There are lots of shortcut ways to do this, but lets start with the easy way:

```
>>> for position,item in enumerate(string_list):
...     how_many = int(display_times[position])
...     print('It is {}'.format(item*how_many))
...
It is aa
It is bbb
It is c
```

You can use `zip` to combine the two lists:

```
>>> zip(string_list, display_times)
[('a', '2'), ('b', '3'), ('c', '1')]
```

Now you can do:

```
>>> for item,how_many in zip(string_list, display_times):
...     print('It is {}'.format(item*int(how_many)))
...
It is aa
It is bbb
It is c
```

There are lot of other ways but they will all involve some variation of the above two.

Comment: This is pretty (the prettiest solution here I think), though as I understand he wants it to be `'It is {}\n'`

Answer (score 1):

```
for i, v in enumerate(display_times):
    for j in range(int(v)):
        print (string_list[i])
```

Or using a LC:

```
r = [[string_list[i] for j in range(int(v))] for i,v in enumerate(display_times)]
for i in r:
   print (i)
```

Comment: Nope sorry, fixed it hahaha

Comment: I believe in python 3.x that would work... (the printing inside LC and all)

Comment: @yuvi Yup, but the list would contain just `None`'s